# Compute SHAP values in R using own ESN implementation

Tags: r, shap

I have an ESN implementation in R for which I want to compute SHAP values (like the minimalESN.r on https://mantas.info/code/simple_esn/). The package for the SHAP values does not matter but all the packages I found need a structured model from lm or xgboost or similar. Is there any way to use an existing package when a structured model is not available? And if not, in what shape / structure do I have to bring my own model for it to work with e.g. shapr or similar?

Edit:
I made some progress and discovered that I need to pass the prediction function to e.g. kernelshap. So I did:

```
ks <- kernelshap(esn_model_shap,
                 train_data,
                 bg_X = bg_temp,
                 pred_fun = predict_esn_shap(esn_model_shap, 
                                             train_data
                                             )
                 )
```

where the prediction function is

```
predict_esn_shap <- function(model, input_data){
  # Wrapper for the prediction function to work with the syntax of 
  # kernelshap.
  
  Win  <- model[[1]]
  W    <- model[[2]]
  Wout <- model[[3]]
  x    <- model[[4]]
  leak <- model[[5]]
  
  test_idx <- 54:60
  
  Y <- predict_ml_model_esn(Win, 
                            W, 
                            Wout, 
                            x, 
                            input_data, 
                            leak, 
                            test_idx, 
                            out_size = 1
                            )
  
  return(Y)
}
```

With this I get the following error message:

```
Error in kernelshap.default(esn_model_shap, train_data, bg_X = bg_temp,  : 
  is.function(pred_fun) is not TRUE
```

The function is defined in a separate file and is found by `kernelshap`. What do I have to change?

Thank you!

Comment: The predict function needs to be a *function*, e.g., `predict_esn_shap` (without any parentheses). Your code passed the *result* of the function, i.e., `predict_esn_shap(...)`.

Comment: Hi, @MichaelM! Thanks for the hint! Now when I run the code I get the error message:
Error in rowsum.default(preds, group = g, reorder = FALSE) : 
  incorrect length for 'group'
How can I fix that?

Comment: Without a simple working code, I can't help. Anyway, for a model with a single feature, there is no need to calculate SHAP values.

Comment: I uploaded a working example to https://github.com/bunteKnete/esn_shap I would be happy if were able to reproduce the error message and had an idea what I need to change.

Comment: Thanks for the example! The result of the `predict()` should be transposed (one row per observation). At least then, the algorithm does something. Now, unfortunately, KernelSHAP algorithms require to repeatedly invert p x p matrices, e.g., via SVD. In your case, p is about 2000, which yields too slow run times. I used the options `hybrid_degree = 0` and `m = 100` for a pure sampling approach of Ian Covert and Su-In Lee (2021), still no chance to get results. I think p = 100 will work, but much larger values are too painful, unfortunately.

Comment: Thanks a lot. Transposing the return vector did the job! Also, it took some time but I obtained results with `p = 2014` and default settings. :)

Comment: Oh wow, you have a monster computer!!